# Missing required modules, SOMETIMES

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have created a Swift framework that includes several other modules inside of it.

When I deployed the framework for others in our company to use, some people were seeing the following message:

Missing required modules: 'Alamofire', 'AlamofireObjectMapper','ObjectMapper'

This message comes up as soon as I put the

```
import ASMCL
```

into my AppDelegate.swift file

Now, for the strange/confusing parts.

I have tried this on 4 different computers, all running the same version of Xcode (8.2.1).  On 3 of them, the framework worked without any errors.  On the 4th computer, I got the error described above.

On my coworkers system, he got the errors.  But, if he zips up his project and I try it on one of the machines that was working for me - it works just fine.

I checked the build settings and could not find any differences between ours.

Even stranger (to me at least), when using this same framework on an Objective-C project, NONE of the users are seeing these errors and the framework works exactly as expected!

As part of my build process, I have a small shell script that re-signs each of the included modules, but don't think that this has anything to do with the issue because I have re-signed the framework and all modules included in it, cleaned my project, and the error still persists.

I have also tried using my personal AppleID, instead of my work one.  On my home computer, I got no errors in my project.  On one of our work Macs, using my same personal AppleID, I got the errors.

Oh, the way I have been importing the framework into my files is by dragging the framework to the "Embedded Binaries" section, and NOT choosing "copy if needed", but putting the path to the location of the framework in the "Framework Search Paths".  I've tried with and without the "recursive" option.  On the computers where things work, I don't need "recursive".

I have also tried to "copy if needed" the framework, but that did not change anything.

I really don't know what else to try!  I can reproduce the issue, but I have yet to find a common reason on the projects where the framework works, and where it has these errror.

Even if some of you could throw some theories/crumbs at me, that would be awesome!  I just don't know what else to check.

Thanks for any/all help given!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer...

I don't think it is currently possible with Swift.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/134265